# failed to conect to the journal socket ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor

Tengo una gota en DigitalOcean en la cual está instalado Nginx y tenía un proyecto funcionando con normalidad, sin embargo, ayer en la noche trate de ingresar por ssh, y no me daba acceso, por lo que ingresé directamente desde la consola que proporciona DigitalOcean, y estos son los datos que me aparecen, no puedo escribir nada y mi proyecto ha dejado de funcionar. Muchas Gracias de antemano :D
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recomendación: si vas a utilizar la versión de StackOverflow en español,  coloca el título de tu pregunta en español.

Comment: Me parece que la forma de resolverlo es una llamada al soporte del proveedor, si no puedes iniciar sesión, difícilmente haya algo que hacer desde fuera.